# MobaXterm stuck at a "progress information" window

Tags: mobaxterm, stm32cubeide

I am using MobaXterm Personal Edition v21.2 Build 4642 to access a remote workbench for educational purposes. The workbench has a Linux machine, and I run STM32CubeIDE to program a development board connected to the remote machine. When I create a new project, the wizard works OK, until it tries to open the ".ioc" file. A "progress information" (thi sis the window bar title) shows up, saying "Initializing Device Configuration Tool...". The progress bar keeps moving back and forth, but then the program looks like if it is stuck at this point.

If I kill the process and restart the IDE, I can see that the ".ioc" file is created. It means that the wizard is working. Then, if I try to open this file, I get stuck in the same way.

When I logged in locally at the workbench machine and used the IDE, it worked without problems. I also connected remotely to the workbench using another linux machine and "pure" (command prompt) ssh. The IDE also worked nicely, which gives me a hint that the problem happens when MobaXterm has to close that "progress information" window and open the "Device configuration tool" window.

Any hints on how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the remote machine runs Linux Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome GUI.